# Use the intermediate value theorem to prove that if $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous, then there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=\sqrt{c}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f(0)<f(1)$. Consider now, $f(0)<\sqrt{c}<f(1)$. By the intermediate value theorem, $\exists b\in[0,1]:f(b)=\sqrt{c}$.

Now we need to show that its possible that $b=c$, but this is exactly where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $g(x)=f(x)-\sqrt x$, $g(0)\leq 0, g(1)\geq 0$, so there exists $c$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-\sqrt c=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. How did you know to do that?